# I have to remove last number and characters in the columns in Python dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a column which has values like this: `34343434,4` and `223232,5`.

I want to remove the last digit and character `,` and expecting like this: `34343434`  `223232`.

I tried using this code:

```py
dataframe['column name'] = pd.to_numeric(dataframe['column name']).astype.float().round(0, 2)
```

But it didn't work. Could somebody help me get the output I desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way using regular expression:

```
dataframe['colname'] = dataframe['colname'].str.replace(',.','',regex=True)
```

[documentation link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Comment: It's coming invalid syntax

Comment: what is the data type of your column? Is it object.